# What are the different ways of integrating svn into the VS-2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

Right now, all I see is "Visual SVN". Are there other alternatives that would let me manage my svn repository from visual studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) from CollabNet, the same company that started Subversion. Like Subversion, AnkhSVN is open source under the Apache license. It's my company's choice for VS to Subversion integration.

Comment: That will be worth a look. Do you know about any others?

Comment: There's [PushOk](http://www.pushok.com/soft_svn.php) and [RocketSVN](http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn), but the biggies are VisualSVN and AnkhSVN. Only AnkhSVN is open source.

Comment: i ended up using ankhSVN. It works well enough for my liking. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent) plugin is an implemention of the *MS-SCCI* version control interface, which means it ties in to all the standard *Visual Studio* version control menus.